# Spark GraphX Runtime Query

Tags: neo4j, spark-graphx

Is it possible to query GraphX at runtime? Or must these queries be compiled and deployed?

If so, is there anything out there that would be the equivalent of Cypher for GraphX?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

yes , it is possible but you have to see the spark Documentation

http://spark.apache.org/screencasts/2-spark-documentation-overview.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.